# How to declare a type whose key and value of an object are associated with enum in TS?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, interface

How to declare the type of an object in typescript, its key is an enumeration member of enum, its value is a function, and the parameters of this function are related to the key?

Details are as follows:

```js
enum Type {
  'select'='select',
  'upload'='upload'
}

type selectProps = {
    options: any[],
    defaultCheckedValue: string
}
type uploadProps = {
  url:string[],
  request:()=>Promise<any>
}
// The otherConfig parameters of the select and upload functions are extended keys based on otherConfig
interface otherComonConfig{
  displayDependOnKeys:Record<string,any>
}
// How to define the correspondence between key and value
type RenderFunc = {
  [key in Type]:<T,U extends otherComonConfig,R>(prop:string,label?:string,options?:T,otherConfig?:U) => R
}

let map:RenderFunc = {
  [Type.select]:(prop,label,options,otherConfig) =>{
    return {
      prop,
      label,
      key:"select",
      options,
      otherConfig
    }
  },
  [Type.upload](prop,label){
    return {
      prop:"handleContent",
      key:'upload'
    };
  }
}
// I hope when i call this methods the options auto map selectOptions,
// At the same time I can also customize the otherConfig type 
// How can i achieve?
map.select('32','dwdw',);
```

I've tried many ways, but it always prompts the wrong type，Can anyone help me？

[See the complete code here -- TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gKClA5AZ2AG2AGMAXLAXlwOLIBoNswF8B7AQwBMKsnXOs0AXzRoSiZHkKkACgCcWCHFHKoGmBSQCWLEDgBcUNiDgBtALr1MmDsABmbMPhIBhABbEA1sA4A1NvjBgAxwSWU0QAHMhUXEoXnYOOQUlFXRMMFl8PRCwyPNLKFlgAEdAkL0ACgBKcgA+JIhNPAAeIzha6IB6Tth3KBYSd1lnHVtNCKgENlk2CGASYFklFlsoQYlqUkMQDjjmBKhbMBBSbV1DIqhgAA8Fne8oLzglACM2PF2dfvXh0fG0cILWT2IjIAZDEYQHQjEBjCJpKAcJrMNhwAAiwCQOwA8iAANLAZ56ABKxBYsg4zRy4QitDaHWEMSQUFJ91kADFjkRlKpMCYnlBwrBxGY9M0YLQAKpXW6gDjLH6Q6F-WnE2oVBDyBDZUI02j4NgvAgAfh1uVpGjOOFNEvBixhcNNkqqylqLOiaEIJCgEDY2tZNg5XJ5CJM8CQADpJDRRRqtfrDQRaJadDhk4qVS66gjMEUSBkQLyrJhNQoCsWDUb8OWrE89AAiaOkes19QILSp1vfCEqtRQYSYQQFMPiCPxThmONlysEKo5wrzAtF4ul7X11xGDiEGF3EgtvuYOs8fb8PuCADcDGEwm6UAAklBXApkAB3dyFzRQIj+fBrVxNH15ifeU-zBdsrUMMASBYH0-SgJsSGxcDOzQW8AEFvXWeDZmQLQ5nvL8jEMfAcBgogwBCFhGgAL1wvo7V+WFxjWWJUJ6AAJFgX0Ij9DCIf9gAAN2AY00F9BAo02EgKiwABmAAmLBaCwDgX1UpSqnPIA)

Comment: What are `selectOptions` and `uploadOptions`?  How specifically should the `options`, `otherConfig`, and return type be related to each enum entry?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NnaAow) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [ask] and consider [edit]ing the question title to conform to them.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I just forgot to post the detailed code, the complete example is posted at the end of the question due to the character limit of the reply, please take a look

Comment: The complete example should be present in the question itself as plaintext.  A playground link is a good supplement but isn't sufficient by itself.  From your link I still don't see how `otherConfig`  is supposed to relate to anything, nor do I understand why the function is supposed to *return* an `OtherCommonConfig`.  The only correlation I can see is between the `RenderType` key and the type of the `options` parameter.  That leads me to something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnaAow), but could you please clarify what you are doing with the return type and the `otherConfig` param?

Comment: And I am still hoping you'll edit that title.  Please spend some time reviewing [ask].  The title should be something like "How to make a type where each property value is a XXXX related to its key by YYY" where you need to fill in XXX and YYY.  Your experience level in TypeScript isn't really relevant enough to be in the title, and it goes without saying that you're asking a question.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that my playground link above didn't do anything useful... look at [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Na1yBN).  Does it work the way you want?  I'm still not understanding how the `OtherCommonConfig` and return types interact with the key or how to figure them out

Comment: @jcalz 
I looked at your code, and your changes are in line with my expectations, but the enum in the code is enumerated one by one in the form of literals. In my actual project, this enumeration option is very long. What I want to know is whether it can be automatically mapped by enumeration and generics? Instead of manually defining them one by one

Comment: Are you talking about changing `enum Type { 'select'='select', 'upload'='upload' }` from your example to something else?  If so then that seems out of scope for the question as asked (I'm happy to advise on such things but probably in a different post, assuming you don't find what you're looking for by searching existing answers).  If not, then can you clarify?

Comment: @jcalz
I mean `enum Type { 'select'='select', 'upload'='upload' } `This enumeration may have many members with similar content, if in interface `PropsMap`
It may not be very convenient to add one by one like this `[Type.select]: xxx`

Comment: @jcalz
My idea can be expressed in the following pseudocode:
`enum T{ a = 'a';b='b'};
type R = {
   [K in T]: <K>(o?: K, otherConfig?: OtherCommonConfig) => any
}
let m: R={
   // Can selectOptions be passed when implementing this member method?
    [Type.select]:<selectOptions>(o,other)=>{}
}`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Are you saying that your enum is fine but you're not happy that the `PropsMap` interface mentions each enum member individually?  If so: you have to specify which options type goes with which enum member *somewhere*; how would you propose doing so without mentioning enum members explicitly?  Where would such information be stored?

Comment: @jcalz
Yes, I hope the `key` in `type RenderFunc` is generated by `key in enum Type`, and then according to the traversed `key`, and then when implementing the method corresponding to `key`, by means of generics , pass the type corresponding to the current `key`. Do you understand what I say?

Comment: What is "the type corresponding to the current `key`"? That mapping needs to be written somewhere.  Can you please spell out where you think that information is stored?

Comment: @jcalz
The storage can be stored in any accessible place. I just want to pass the `props` to the parameter list of the property method through generics when implementing the object property method.

Comment: I’m afraid you’re not understanding my question and at this point I think it is unlikely that further questions will improve the situation.  I see two options: either I answer the posted question with my current solution and an explanation; or, I do not and hopefully someone else will come along to help you.  Which of those two options do you prefer?

Comment: @jcalz
I'm sorry, maybe I'm not very clear, I just started using typesctipt, maybe the effect I want may not support this kind of operation itself

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be a communication barrier between us, so I will have to stop interacting here.  Sorry.  Good luck to you!